# Using Captcha with Meteor's accounts-ui-bootstrap-3

Tags: javascript, meteor, npm, captcha

When using the combination of Meteor packages `accounts-ui-bootstrap-3` and `accounts-password`, how can we to include Captcha verification?

How would you integrate a package like [captchagen](https://github.com/wearefractal/captchagen) with `accounts-ui`?

Answer (score 2):

In implemented my own solution using Google [Recaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/) directly

What I've done

1. Download Recaptcha .js files and put them in `lib`
2. in my `html` page added `<div id="recaptchaDiv"></div>`
3. In client code added

`Template.YOUR_TEMPLATE.rendered = function () {
  Recaptcha.create("YOUR_RECAPTCHA_KEY",
    "recaptchaDiv",
    {
      theme: "red",
      callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
    }
  );
};`

On the server side I have a method:

```
validateCaptcha: function(challenge, resp){
  var self = this;
  var ip = self.connection.clientAddress;
  var result = HTTP.post('http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify', {params: {
    privatekey:"YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY",
    remoteip:ip,
    challenge:challenge,
    response:resp,
  }});

  if(result.statusCode === 200){
    if(result.content==="true\nsuccess")
      return "success";

    return "fail";
  }
}
```

Then when your validate the form you call this method

```
Meteor.call("validateCaptcha",Recaptcha.get_challenge(),Recaptcha.get_response(),function(res){
        if(res=="ok"){
          console.log("it works")
        }else{
          Recaptcha.reload();
          console.log("wrong captacha")
        }
      });
```

You may need to change some code in the package itself to add it to `accounts-ui`

Hope it helps